# React - SetState handler Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, react-hooks, setstate

I have a component with the following situation:

These are two methods when i select two teams (**Home**, **Away**) in two select components

```
  const selectHomeTeamStat = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    setSelectedHomeOption(value);
    getStats(leagueId, value, 'home');
  };

  const selectAwayTeamStat = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    setSelectedAwayOption(value);
    getStats(leagueId, value, 'away');
  };
```

As you can see i am able to pass this string parameter '**Home**' and '**Away**' to the `getStats` request in order to differentiate and create then two different states

After that i have realized that instead of the strings '**Home**' and '**Away**' i actually need the **state name of the teams** to pass as parameter to the `getStats` request

So this changed to

```
  const [selectedHomeName, setSelectedHomeName] = useState("");
  const [selectedAwayName, setSelectedAwayName] = useState("");

  const selectHomeTeamStat = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    const item = items.find(item => item.team_id == value);
    setSelectedHomeOption(value);
    setSelectedHomeName(item.name);
    console.log('Home Team Name:', selectedHomeName);
    getStats(leagueId, value, selectedHomeName);
  };

  const selectAwayTeamStat = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    const item = items.find(item => item.team_id == value);
    setSelectedAwayOption(value);
    setSelectedAwayName(item.name);
    console.log('Away Team name:', selectedAwayName);
    getStats(leagueId, value, selectedAwayName);
  };
```

`item.name` returns correctly the name of the team selected so then i expect to see `selectedHomeName` and `selectedAwayName` states too but in my `console.log` i don't see the it

```
console.log('Home Team Name:', selectedHomeName); => Team Name:
console.log('Away Team Name:', selectedAwayName); => Away Name:
```

So the question is, what am i doing wrong? how can i pass **these states** to `getStats` inside the event handler in order to differentiate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous. You are logging the state in the current render phase, the updated value will be available only on the next render.

To fix it, pass the current value `item.name` or use `useEffect`

```
const selectHomeTeamStat = (evt) => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    setSelectedHomeOption(value);
}

useEffect(() => {
  const item = items.find((item) => item.team_id == selectedHomeOption);
  getStats(leagueId, selectedHomeOption, item.name);
}, [leagueId, items, selectedHomeOption]);
```

Comment: i understand this solution but i have this error in UseEffect =>  'value' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: That's should be `selectedHomeOption` which you used in `setSelectedHomeOption`

Comment: `setState` is async means the value you pass it will _eventually_ make it into the state, but that's not the reason the code is logging the previous value. If it were sync, it would still be logging the previous value. You are associating two completely unrelated ideas here.

Comment: items is an empty array in this case when it is in useEffect, i will reproduce a codesandbox

Comment: I accept this answer because it has been more focused to my case. thanks for the time and explanation

Answer (score 6):

That's logging the previous value, as that was the one in scope when the function was defined, before calling it.

If you actually want to log the right value that is going to eventually (as `setState` is async) make it into the state on that same spot, simply log `item.name`.

Alternatively, if you want to log the value only after it's already in the state, then you should use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect), passing it the values you want to react to as `deps`:

```
// We want React to call this function every time `selectedAwayName` changes:
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Away Team name:', selectedAwayName);
}, [selectedAwayName]);
```

Here you can see what is going on and how `useEffect` fixes it:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [selectedHomeName, setSelectedHomeName] = React.useState('');
  const [selectedAwayName, setSelectedAwayName] = React.useState('');

  // When the component renders for the first time, this function is created,
  // and the `selectedHomeName` value that will log when called is the one
  // currently in scope, that is, an empty string.
  
  // When the component re-renders, a new function is created again with the
  // value currently in scope, which is the one we set previously. When changed
  // again, it will log the previous value, not the new one:
  
  const selectHomeTeamStat = ({ target }) => {
    setSelectedHomeName(target.textContent);
    console.log('PREVIOUS Home Team =', selectedHomeName);
  };

  const selectAwayTeamStat = ({ target }) => {
    setSelectedAwayName(target.textContent);
    console.log('PREVIOUS Away Team =', selectedAwayName);
  };
  
  // We are telling React to call this function every time `selectedHomeName` or
  // `selectedAwayName` change:
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`CURRENT TEAMS = ${ selectedHomeName } / ${ selectedAwayName }`);
  }, [selectedHomeName, selectedAwayName])
  
  return (<React.Fragment>
    <nav className="buttons">
      <button onClick={ selectHomeTeamStat }>Home Team 1</button>
      <button onClick={ selectHomeTeamStat }>Home Team 2</button>
      <button onClick={ selectAwayTeamStat }>Away Team 1</button>
      <button onClick={ selectAwayTeamStat }>Away Team 2</button>    
    </nav>
    
    <div>{ selectedHomeName } / { selectedAwayName }</div>
  </React.Fragment>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body,
button {
  font-family: monospace;
}

body, p {
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin: 32px 0;
}

button {
  margin: 0 4px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 45px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

With these changes in mind, you can now use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) so that those two functions are not re-created on each re-render, as they don't need to access `selectedHomeName` or `selectedAwayName` anymore:

```
const selectHomeTeamStat = React.useCallback(({ target }) => {
  setSelectedHomeName(target.textContent);
}, []);

const selectAwayTeamStat = React.useCallback(({ target }) => {
  setSelectedAwayName(target.textContent);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, i can not use item.name because i want to differentiate the item.name from Home Team and the item.name from Away team

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem with that. The `item.name` inside `selectHomeTeamStat` would not be the same as the one inside `selectAwayTeamStat`. In any case, I'd go for `useEffect` and `useCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log('Home Team Name:', selectedHomeName);
getStats(leagueId, value, selectedHomeName);
```

and

```
console.log('Away Team name:', selectedAwayName);
getStats(leagueId, value, selectedAwayName);
```

Will always be the previous value of `selectedHomeName` and `selectedAwayName`.
It is because you set the value which will be updated at the next render in you event handlers.

You should use `item.name` to pass to `getStats`. You can use `selectedHomeName` and `selectedAwayName` in render or somewhere else or as [Danzinger's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61677134/5923584) suggest you can listen for changes on them with `useEffect`

```
const selectHomeTeamStat = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    const item = items.find(item => item.team_id == value);
    setSelectedHomeOption(value);
    setSelectedHomeName(item.name);
    console.log('Home Team Name:', item.name);
    getStats(leagueId, value, item.name);
  };

  const selectAwayTeamStat = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    const item = items.find(item => item.team_id == value);
    setSelectedAwayOption(value);
    setSelectedAwayName(item.name);
    console.log('Away Team name:', item.name);
    getStats(leagueId, value, item.name);
  };
```